# Rule-based column renaming in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to rename the Pandas columns according to rules. They were originally merged cells in an excel document. I've imported the file into pandas and several columns are now unnamed. I wish to rename them according to the column to their left. For example.

**`'ID' 'Name' 'Volts' 'Unnamed: 4' 'Upstream' 'Unnamed: 6' 'Unnamed: 7' 'Unnamed: 8'`**

I want to rename 4 to volts, and 6 7 and 8 to upstream, in an automated way, so that all unnamed columns take the last title to their left. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not good practice to have a non unique index, this will lead to issues when selecting columns. You can do this but I advise against it.

Comment: I should possibly have added the second part of my plan, effectively the "titles" are actually split across 4 rows of excel, so upstream then has unique identifiers, for example upstream physical issue, upstream financial issue etc. What I'm looking for is a way to merge these titles into one per column, thereby creating a unique index, so the full title would be "Upstream Physical Issue". I thought this would be the first step, maybe I'm starting at the wrong point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kindly follow Ed's advice and not dupe names. That said, this will give you a possible way to deal with your issue that you can adapt further:

```
s = df.columns.to_series()

s
Out[27]: 
ID                  ID
Name              Name
Volts            Volts
Unnamed:4    Unnamed:4
Upstream      Upstream
Unnamed:6    Unnamed:6
Unnamed:7    Unnamed:7
Unnamed:8    Unnamed:8
dtype: object

s[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')] = np.nan

s.ffill()
Out[29]: 
ID                 ID
Name             Name
Volts           Volts
Unnamed:4       Volts
Upstream     Upstream
Unnamed:6    Upstream
Unnamed:7    Upstream
Unnamed:8    Upstream
dtype: object

df.columns = s.ffill()

df
Out[31]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, Name, Volts, Volts, Upstream, Upstream, Upstream, Upstream]
Index: []
```